# Deserialize the json to c# object

Tags: c#, json

```
{
    "0": {
        "no": "tenon",
        "title": "ProdtesterTITLE439",
        "stock": 12
    },
    "success": 1
}
```

I want  to desrialize those json.The problem is I cant create class with name 0 in c sharp.i have  tried

```
[JsonObject(Title = "0")]
```

and

```
[DataContract(Name ="0")]
```

Not one of them are worked.

---

Answer (score 3):

Good news! Your root object doesn't have a name, so you don't need to create a class with that name. `0` is a property of the root object.

Of course, `0` isn't a valid property name in C# either. That's where [`JsonPropertyAttribute`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) comes in:

```
public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("0")]
    public MyData Data {get;set;}
    public bool Success {get;set;}
}

public class MyData
{
    public int Stock {get;set;}
    // other properties
}
```